# How can I do a t.test on an entire data.frame and extract the p-values?

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

My dataset looks something like this:

```
a <- rnorm(2)
b <- rnorm(2)-3
x <- rnorm(13)
y <- rnorm(2)-1
z <- rnorm(2)-2
eg <- expand.grid(a,b,x,y,z)
treatment <- c(rep(1, 2), rep(0,3))
eg <- data.frame(t(eg))
row.names(eg) <- NULL
eg <- cbind(treatment, eg)
```

What I need to do is run t-tests on each column, comparing the treatment =1 group to the treatment=0 group. I'd like to then have a vector of p-values. I've tried (several versions of) doing this through a loop, but I continue to receive the same error message: "undefined columns selected." Here's my code currently:

```
p.values <- c(rep(NA, 208))

for (i in 2:209) {
  x <- data.frame(eg[eg$treatment==1][,i][1:2])
  y <- data.frame(eg[eg$treatment==0][,i][3:5])
  value <- t.test(x=x, y=y)['p.value']
  p.values[i] <- value
}
```

I added the data.frame() after reading someone mention that for loops only loop through dataframes, but it didn't change anything. I am sure there is an easier way to do this, perhaps by using something in the apply family? Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

A couple of options, both using `sapply`:

```
sapply(
  eg[-1], function(x) t.test(x[eg$treatment==1],x[eg$treatment==0])[["p.value"]] 
)
```

Or looping over the names instead:

```
sapply(
  names(eg[-1]), 
  function(x) t.test(as.formula(paste(x,"~ treatment")),data=eg)[["p.value"]] 
)
```

Or even `mapply`:

```
mapply(function(x,y) t.test(x ~ y,data=cbind(x,y))[["p.value"]], eg[-1], eg[1])
```